# Question about linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

The linear transformation $L : \Bbb R^4 → \Bbb R^4$ projects $\Bbb R^4$ orthogonally onto the subspace $V =\text{span}\{a, b\}$, with $a = (1, 1, 1, 1)$, and $b = (4, 2, 1, 2)$

For the first question:

Find the matrix $[L]$ which represents $L$ with respect to standard coordinates.

Does this question mean just to find the matrix which projects $\Bbb R^4$ spans $\{a,b\}$?
I'm confused with this part

and I have following questions:

b) How does L transform vectors in the nullspace of $[L]$? and how does L transform vectors in the column space of $[L]$? Could you explain please?

c) How can I find the rank and the nullity of $[L]$ without row reduction just through solving the question (a)?

Help please
Thanks

Comment: Rank of $[L]$ is the same as the dimension of the range of $L$. What do you think that is?

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203355/null-space-column-space-and-rank-with-projection-matrix/2203388#2203388).

Comment: Yes, the first part of the question is asking you to find the matrix which projects vectors onto the subspace $V$.