# Liner algebra transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, orthogonality

How would you do these questions? would you find the orthogonal basis for the given a and b? How would you find the transform???
The linear transformation $L : \mathbb{R}^4 → \mathbb{R}^4$ projects $\mathbb{R}^4$ orthogonally onto the subspace V =$\text{span}\{a, b\}$, with $a = (1, 1, 1, 1)$ and $b = (4, 2, 1, 2)$

For the first question:

Find the matrix $[L]$ which represents $L$ with respect to standard coordinates.

Does this question mean just to find the matrix which projects $\mathbb{R}^4$ spans $\{a,b\}$? I'm confused with this part

and I have following questions:

b) How does $L$ transform vectors in the nullspace of $[L]$? and how does L transform vectors in the column space of $[L]$? Could you explain please?

c) How can I find the rank and the nullity of $[L]$ without row reduction just through solving part (a)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null space, column space and rank with projection matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203355/null-space-column-space-and-rank-with-projection-matrix)

Comment: really? just can't get started though Do I find a orthogonal basis by doing  the gram smith process?How would I do transformations?

Comment: Yes you can find $c$ such that span{$a,c$} = span{$a,b$} for example with $a \perp c$. I don't understand what you mean with: "The linear transformation L:ℝ4→ℝ4L:R4→R4 projects ℝ4R4 orthogonally onto the subspace V =span{a,b}span{a,b}, with a=(1,1,1,1)a=(1,1,1,1) and b=(4,2,1,2)" Is this right? $L:\mathbb{R}^n → V$?

Comment: Parts (b) and (c) are covered in [the cited question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203355/null-space-column-space-and-rank-with-projection-matrix). Note that you don’t actually have to find $[L]$ to answer them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only part of your question that’s not already answered [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203355/null-space-column-space-and-rank-with-projection-matrix) is how to construct $[L]$, which is indeed the matrix that projects vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ onto $V=\operatorname{span}\{a,b\}$.

One way is to first find an orthogonal basis for $V$, which you can do via the Gram-Schmidt process. $V$ is generated by only two vectors, so this will be a fairly quick computation. Note that you can take a shortcut by taking $a$ and the orthogonal rejection of $b$ from $a$ as your basis. Projection onto $V$ is then the sum of the individual projections onto the basis vectors, which can be found via scalar products. The projection of a vector $\mathbf x$ onto another vector $\mathbf v$ is $$\left(\mathbf x\cdot{\mathbf v\over\|\mathbf v\|}\right){\mathbf v\over\|\mathbf v\|} = {\mathbf x\cdot\mathbf v\over\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf v}\mathbf v={\mathbf v^T\mathbf x\over\mathbf v^T\mathbf v}\mathbf v={\mathbf v\mathbf v^T\over\mathbf v^T\mathbf v}\mathbf x.$$ The coefficient of $\mathbf x$ in the last expression is a matrix that projects onto $\mathbf v$. For this problem, this method is the simplest.

It’s obvious that $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent, and so are a basis for $V$. If you have any basis of $V$, another way to find the matrix that projects onto $V$ is to form the matrix $B$ that has the basis vectors as its columns. The matrix that projects onto $V$ is then given by the well-known formula $B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T$.

Yet another way is to use the answers to the other parts of the question. There is some basis of $\mathbb R^4$ in which the matrix of $L$ is the diagonal matrix $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,1,0,0)$. This corresponds to decomposing $\mathbb R^4$ into the direct sum $V\oplus V^\perp$. So, find a basis for $V$ and a basis for its orthogonal complement, and use that to convert this diagonal matrix to the standard basis. I.e., let $B$ be the matrix with the first two columns a basis for $V$ and the last two a basis for $V^\perp$. Relative to the standard basis, the projection matrix is then $BDB^{-1}$.